# Set tomcat initial connection pool on startup

Tags: java, tomcat, connection

Im looking for information about how to enable connection pooling on tomcat startup. My setting right makes tomcat to initilize and add X number of connections to the pool upon the first request, but I would like tomcat to do this upon starting tomcat.

My setting in Server.xml is as follows:

```
<Context docBase=".../apache-tomcat-5.5.27/webapps/app" path="/app" reloadable="true" 
source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:app">
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="100" 
maxIdle="30" initialSize="10" 
maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/app" password="pass" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/dbschema" username="username"/>
```

As I mentioned earlier, setting initialSize to 10 creates 10 connections when the first connection is created, but I would like this functionality when starting tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this and I will answer my own question in case someone else needs it.

Solved this by creating a servlet, overriding the init() method and had that servlet load on startup by modifying web.xml in tomcat. This works as long as `initialSize` is already set in the servlet.xml.

So, what actually happends is that tomcat loads this servlet on startup, and all this servlet does is to create a database connection. When this connection is created, tomcat will start the number of connections specified in initialSize